# Form does not read javascript before redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form, before submit the data to another page it needs to validate the input first. But the problem is the form redirect to another page without reading the javascript first.

```
<html>
<script>
    function fnValidate(){
     with document.frmAdd{
    var x;
    x = txtEmail.value;

    if( x.indexof("@")== -1)
    {   alert("A valid email address must contains @"); 
    return false; }
    if( isNaN(txtAge.value)== 1- )
    {   alert("Age must be filled out by number");
    return false; }
    if( txtPwd.value <> txtPwd2.value )
    {   alert("Password not matched!");
    return false; }

     } //end_with
    } //end_fnValidate()

</script>
<body>
    <form name="frmAdd" method="post" action="SaveNewUser.php" onSubmit="return fnValidate()">
        IC No    : <input type=text name="txtIc" size=20 required> <br>
        Name     : <input type=text name="txtName" size=50 required> <br>
        Email    : <input type=text name="txtEmail" size=50 required> <br>
        D.O.B    : <input type=date name="txtDOB" size=20 required> <br>
        Age      : <input type=text name="txtAge" size=5 maxlength=2 required> 
        <br><br>
        Username         : <input type=text name="txtUserName" size=20 
            required> <br>
        Password         : <input type=password name="txtPwd" size=20 
            required> <br>
        Re-Enter Password: <input type=password name="txtPwd2" size=20 
            required> <br><br>
        <input type=submit name=btnSubmit value=SAVE> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to call a function.

Comment: In your `fnValidate` function, have a parameter called `event` and then inside the function use `event.preventDefault();` at the very start of your function. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @RobertCooper its not working :(

Comment: @MerajKhan I just called it using onSubmit="return fnValidate()"

Comment: The [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) syntax ... Hit F12 and find a new world from your favorite browser ...

Comment: @Teemu I got Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on console. I believe the 'with' cause the problem. What is the alternative?

Comment: A recommended alternative would be to wrap a reference in a variable, or just write the `with` statement correctly.

Comment: @Mohd Ariffin you didn't define `txtEmail`

Comment: @MohdAriffin You really have to take more careful look at your code, there are several errors in the small snippet. The `with` syntax fails + don't rely on document having named elements as properties. What is `indexof` method? what kind of an operator is `<>`? What is  `if ( isNaN(txtAge.value)== 1- )` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add return to your java script function at the end

```
function fnValidate()
{
    with document.frmAdd{

    var x;
    x = txtEmail.value;

    if( x.indexof("@")== -1)
    {   alert("A valid email address must contains @"); 
        return false; }
    if( isNaN(txtAge.value)== 1- )
    {   alert("Age must be filled out by number");
        return false; }
    if( txtPwd.value <> txtPwd2.value )
    {   alert("Password not matched!");
        return false; }

    } 

return false;
}
```

Comment: Why've you left the obvious syntax error in the code?

Comment: And why are you canceling the submission when validating succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript functions should be placed inside script tags :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function fnValidate()
    {
        with document.frmAdd{

        var x;
        x = txtEmail.value;

        if( x.indexof("@")== -1)
        {   alert("A valid email address must contains @"); 
            return false; }
        if( isNaN(txtAge.value)== 1- )
        {   alert("Age must be filled out by number");
            return false; }
        if( txtPwd.value <> txtPwd2.value )
        {   alert("Password not matched!");
            return false; }

        } //end_with
    } //end_fnValidate()

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    .
    .
    .
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Indeed, but syntax errors should also be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `with` statement expression with a round brackets. That being said, the use of the `with` statement is not recommended anymore (see the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)).

```
function fnValidate()
{
  with (document.frmAdd) {
    var x;
    x = txtEmail.value;
    if( x.indexof("@")== -1)
    {   alert("A valid email address must contains @"); 
        return false; }
    if( isNaN(txtAge.value)== 1- )
    {   alert("Age must be filled out by number");
        return false; }
    if( txtPwd.value <> txtPwd2.value )
    {   alert("Password not matched!");
    return false; }
  } //end_with
  return;
} //end_fnValidate()
```

Comment: Well, I gave it my best effort!

Comment: Done! Not sure if the corrected with statement syntax will help the OP, but hopefully it does 